# jsPDF not working with images

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am trying to generate pdf on client-side using jsPDF library. My code looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/sprintf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>

<script>
var doc = new jsPDF();
var imgData = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(30, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.output('datauri');
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 200, 114);
</script>
```

but it seems to print text only and no image.
What is the problem here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you want to add a png image, you have to get the latest jspdf.js and add the support png libraries

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/png_support/zlib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/png_support/png.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.png_support.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>
```

then in the script, change the format to 'PNG'

```
<script>
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var imgData = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAABy...
    doc.setFontSize(40);
    doc.text(30, 20, 'Hello world!');
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 15, 40, 200, 114);
    doc.output('datauri');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Include the following file to your HTML:

```
<script src="Scripts/jspdf/png_support/zlib.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jspdf/png_support/png.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jspdf/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jspdf/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jspdf/jspdf.plugin.png_support.js"></script>
```

You can get all these files from https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

FileSaver.js from libs/FileSaver.js
zlib.js and png.js from libs/png_support.js

If you don't need to save pdf file, you can exclude FileSaver.js.

When it alerts missing some functions, opening dist/jspdf.debug.js, search for it name to find particular module containing it and include it in above list(after jspdf.js file).

Comment: It should not be necessary to have the FileSaver.js resource because jspdf already includes what it needs for downloading/saving. (I have tested with jspdf Version 1.5.3)

Answer (score 2):

call `doc.output` after building the doc:

```
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 200, 114);
doc.output('datauri');
```

Comment: @AZee can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a library like react you can store it in a state and show it in the view, when you are exporting that the image will be shown,

```
const [image, setImage] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const loadImage = async () => {
      let imageUrl =
        "your-image-url";
      let imageUrlFetched = await fetch(imageUrl);
      let blob = await imageUrlFetched.blob();
      let fileName = imageUrl.substring(imageUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
      let file = new File([blob], fileName, { type: blob.type });
      setImage(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    };

    loadImage();
  }, []);
```

Finally you can put the state in image src,

```
 <img src={image} alt="" />
```

Answer (score -6):

jsPDF supports only **JPEG** format of the images for now.

Your image `var imgData = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...` is in PNG format.