# image to base64 conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, jspdf

I want to convert a images to base64 format for my chrome extension.

```
CODE:
var img_src = $('#elementId').attr('src');
converImgToBase64(img_src)
function convertImgToBase64(url)
{

    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    img = document.createElement('img'),
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function()
    {
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;


        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        alert(dataURL);

        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.addImage(dataURL, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
       doc.output('datauristring');
        canvas = null; 

    };
}
```

Alert box correctly shows the base64 format of  image but **PDF IS NOT GENERATING**?
How can i generate pdf for my image

Comment: I have also used addHTML() to convert the image into pdf  by it's class name but i am not getting any results

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is not having an image in base64, but generating a pdf from it. So please, mind a little more you title next time ;)

By googling all these matters, I found this : http://parall.ax/products/jspdf which, i think, should help you.

As you can see, the homepage example look likes doing all that you need ;)

Comment: I am already using jspdf see code but  i am not getting the output image

Comment: mmh, that would be very helpfull to mention. So, what did you get ?

Comment: i getting a white pdf no images are there

Comment: Here is your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072241/jspdf-not-working-with-images

Comment: Just for information, I google your problem and found the solution, on this one I help you, but people rarely answer to matters that don't even give informations, and with a wrong title...