# How could I save a jsPDF with images on server?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, base64, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF to create PDF's on client-side.
Now, I have Pictures in my PDF and I want so save this on my server.

The Problem is, without images there's no problem, but with images the generated PDF is corrupt.

How could I solve this?

Javascript:

```
var pdf = doc.output(); 
var data = new FormData();
data.append("data" , pdf);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( 'post', 'ajax/upload.php', true );
xhr.send(data);
```

PHP:

```
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
 $data = $_POST['data'];
 $fname = "einsatz.pdf"; // name the file
 $file = fopen("../data/" .$fname, 'w'); // open the file path
 fwrite($file, $data); //save data
 fclose($file);
 echo "Einsatzblatt saved";
}
else {
 echo "No Data Sent";
}
```

Thank You for your help!

**UPDATE** 05/29/2015

The image is generated from google maps with a blockspring plugin.
there I get a base64 png.

```
blockspring.runParsed("b21fb2a7b862354a76a7806ae9fc0a4d", { "color": "#d52c11", "zoom_level": 16, "address": ""+ adresse + "" }, { "api_key": "br_3080_5cec24d3c19bdc66c763138a974e14311facf637" }, function(res){
var imgData = 'data:image/png;base64,' + res.params.maps.data;
```

Then I create the PDF

```
var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 150, 45, 125, 125);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jsPDF not working with images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072241/jspdf-not-working-with-images)

Comment: Possibly, but we can't really tell without seeing how the PDF is generated and how it is "corrupt"

Comment: No, that's not the same! It works with images on client-side (doc.save('example.pdf')), but if I want to send it to server to save the PDF direct on server, then is the PDF corrupt. If the PDF without images then works the server-side saving!

Answer (score 1):

I encoded to `base64` in java script and then decoded it back in server, it worked for me.

Here is my code snippet.

Javascript:

```
data: {pdfContent:btoa(pdfContent)}
```

PHP:

```
$pdfContent = base64_decode($this->request->data['pdfContent']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should wait until all images are downloaded. Faced the similar issue with another JS script that generates PDF and the solution was to add img tags with same images in HTML so the workflow will be like this:

- user loads page
- images are loaded into the hidden div:

```
<!-- hidden images for pdf generation - BEGIN -->
<div id="pdfreportimages" style="display: none;">
    <!-- put images you plan to use in PDF below -->

    <img src="pdfreportimages/logo.jpg" id="pdflogoimage"> 

</div>
<!-- hidden images for pdf generation - END -->
```

- javascript that is placed below the "pdfreportimages" div is executed then and generates PDF

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I think that the problem is due to string encoding during the post.

if you use an ajax script to pass data (like this)

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'data_pdf': pdf
                },
            })
```

you will be able to save anyway the pdf file but there is not trace of the image (images) and I think the problem is due to encoding during the POST.

I hope someone can help us..

Comment: This is not an answer to fix the problem.

Comment: I know it, but it's a step to do it. If we could understand how to avoid the encoding of the string passed to the php script.