# How to add image to node-jspdf

Tags: node.js, jspdf

Hy, I need help.I am new in Node.js. I am doing pdf on server side (Node.js). I downloaded file from https://github.com/calvinfroedge/node-jspdf and install it. When I try this code:

```
require('node-jspdf');
var name="file";
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, "Octonyan loves jsPDF");
doc.save(name+'.pdf');
```

It works perfect. Then I add this code to add image to pdf: http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/#. I get an error for 'atob'. I install: npm install atob. Then I get this error:

```
node_modules/node-jspdf/vendor/jsPDF/plugins/png_support.js:362
            throw new Error("PNG support requires png.js and zlib.js");
```

PNG support requires png.js and zlib.js

Any idea how to fix this??
Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsPDF not working with images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072241/jspdf-not-working-with-images)

Comment: I fix the error for 'atob'. The solution was that I must install 'atob' and 'btoa' inside node-jspdf/vendor/jspdf. Then in addImage.js I must add:   var atob = require('atob')
    , b64 = "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ="
    , bin = atob(b64); Now I have no errors, pdf is created, BUT there is no image in pdf

Comment: @R.Turner I am working on the same thing. Where you able to acomplish adding the image?