# jsPDF not rendering highcharts image on Edge browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, jspdf, html2canvas

I am new to jsPDF and I am trying to download the `highchart` with some html content. My code works fine for all browser except "Microsoft Edge".
Here is the working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LTZHOc?p=preview).  I have googled similar questions but none of them talk about edge browser, additionally, I have tried using png image instead of JPEG  like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072241/jspdf-not-working-with-images) but no luck.

**Note**: I have tried passing directly image url to .addImage() function which works fine with all browser.

Can someone please point me, what I am missing or doing wrong?

Update: Till Edge version 20 the code works fine, problem is with above 20 versions.

Comment: what if multiple chart will be there like whose id will be dynamic like instead of $('#testchart').find('svg').width(); it will be $('chart-'+index).find('svg').width();

Comment: In that case, you just need to tweak your code a little bit, the implementation will remain same with some additional code for your multiple charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to an Edge-Canvas issue, I suppose.

Instead of SVG->Canvas, I used SVG->Blob->Image->Canvas approach.

On my local Edge, I had the problem that you mentioned in the post. With my version it works well on Edge too.

Here is what I did:

```
 $scope.chartWithContentDownload = function() {
        var doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt', 'a4', true);
        var elementHandler = {
            '#ignorePDF' : function(element, renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        var source = document.getElementById("top-content");
        doc.fromHTML(source, 15, 15, {
            'width' : 560,
            'elementHandlers' : elementHandler
        });


        var msie = document.documentMode;

  if (!isNaN(msie) && msie < 12) {
  // code for IE < 12

      var tempSVG = $('#testchart').highcharts().container.innerHTML;
                var canvas11 = document.createElement('canvas');

                canvg(canvas11, tempSVG);
                var dataUrl = canvas11.toDataURL('image/JPEG');

                doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'JPEG', 20, 300, 560, 350);

                var source2 = document.getElementById("bottom-content");
                doc.fromHTML(source2, 15, 650, {
                    'width' : 560,
                    'elementHandlers' : elementHandler
                });

                setTimeout(function() {
                    doc.save('TestChart.pdf');
                }, 2000);

  } else {

    var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
        var width = $('#testchart').find('svg').width();
        var height = $('#testchart').find('svg').height();
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
    var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);

    var img = new Image();
    var svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

    img.onload = function () {
      ctx.canvas.width = width;
      ctx.canvas.height = height;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
      DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

      var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'JPEG', 20, 300, 560, 350);

            var source2 = document.getElementById("bottom-content");
            doc.fromHTML(source2, 15, 650, {
                'width' : 560,
                'elementHandlers' : elementHandler
            });

            setTimeout(function() {
                doc.save('TestChart.pdf');
            }, 2000);
    };

    img.src = url;

}

};
```

[Plunker Link is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/8GLKJZjQXDWuK8ecsXON?p=preview)

**Note:**

I only checked on Chrome and Edge.

My Edge version is: **Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0**

My Chrome version is: **Version 56.0.2924.87**

---

**Edit**

There was a bug on IE 11 about *canvas.toDataUrl() security error.* I fixed it and updated the code. Now it checks the browser and behave different on IE 11. The OP's original code works well on IE 11, so i didn't do anything new for that, I am just checking the client browser IE version.

There is a special property in Angular, used like this: `var msie = document.documentMode;`. If the browser is IE, msie will be NaN. If it is IE, msie is the version number.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L204-L209

---

Comment: I just tested today in IE 11, and its giving me "Security Error" exception on canvas.toDtatURL(). I have tried some of the solutions but mostly answers are saying to use canvg which again revert me backs to original problem.

Comment: @CodeReady, i updated the answer code, it now works on my IE11 and Edge both.

Comment: Cool! I too did the same thing in a different way to determine IE browser. Here is my Plunkr(https://plnkr.co/edit/LTZHOc?p=info
)