JavaScript PDF generator will not load image
Working on a Django project, basically this function is supposed to generate a printable PDF when the button click calls it. It works, apart from the fact the image (company logo) will not show in the PDF. Any idea where I am going wrong? Here is my function:
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#cmd').click(function () {
                    var element = document.querySelector("#pdf");
                    var button = document.getElementById("cmd");
                    button.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the button

                    html2canvas(element, {
                        onrendered: function(canvas) {
                            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
                            var imgWidth = 210;
                            var pageHeight = 297;
                            var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
                            var heightLeft = imgHeight;
                            var position = 0;

                            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                            heightLeft -= pageHeight;

                            while (heightLeft >= 0) {
                                position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
                                pdf.addPage();
                                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                                heightLeft -= pageHeight;
                            }
                            pdf.save('sample-file.pdf');
                            button.style.display = 'block'; // Show the button again
                        }
                    });
                });
            });


         </script>


Did you add the necessary libraries ? See the link please...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072241/jspdf-not-working-with-images
